# No POST data after dynamically creating a form and submitting it

Tags: php, angularjs, forms

I am creating a little shop system for myself (learning purpose) using **AngularJS** and **PHP**, and I am stuck with the following problem:

I created a dynamic shopping cart and filled it on `ng-click` with some information of the clicked object in the list. I saved to a scope variable called `scope.cart`which is then shown by `ng-repeat` within the shopping cart table. I then also automatically created input fields which are hidden to pass them to the `$_POST` variable after submit. Because my POST is empty after submitting, I tried to use the `ng-submit` directive to create a json file out of the `scope.cart` array at the time the formula is sent, so I can then call it via PHP. But this doesn*t work either. Now I am stuck and have no clue what the problem could be.

However I think that the input field is empty even though the browser adds new fields dynamically in the source code, and when I hit submit there is the state of the empty cart.

Whats the best way to solve my problem and send the AngJS data to the server?

```js
navApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http){
scope.submit = function() {
  var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  
  http.post('../dampfen/cfg/orders/cart_' + time + '.json', scope.cart).then(function(data) {
   alert("Order successfully transferred!");
  });
 }
}]);
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead><tr><th colspan="4">Bestellung</th></thead><tbody>
<form name="orderForm" method="POST" ng-submit="submit()" action="index.php?checkout">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="{{item.id}}" />
   <td>1x</td><td><strong>{{item.name}}</strong></td><td>{{item.preis}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></td><td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td></tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
    <p class="text-right"><strong>{{cart.sum}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></strong></p>
    <p class="text-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Checkout</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteCart()">Warenkorb l&ouml;schen</button></p>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form>` elements cannot be child nodes of `<tbody>` elements.

You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have an entire form inside a table *cell*.

Anything else leads to browser error recovery that can dump the form outside the table leaving the inputs behind.

Use [basic QA](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). Write valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Will learn the appropriate structures.